# php includes not working with relative path - DocumentRoot issue? MAMP?

Tags: php, apache, server-side-includes

There has to be something I'm overlooking but I can't seem to get my includes to work as expected using relative paths. In MAMP the DocumentRoot is configured in httpd.conf like this:

```
# MAMP DOCUMENT_ROOT !! Don't remove this line !!
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/projects/journalproject”
```

I bring up the site at http://localhost:8888/ and the includes work fine if I use a path like this:

```
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
```

But, if I put my include file into a folder, the include doesn't show up on the page:

```
<?php include('/includes/nav.php'); ?>
```

This is the path of the include file: /journalproject/includes/nav.php

I'm calling it from here: /journalproject/journals/index.php

I can also get the include to work if I use a path like this:

```
<?php include('../includes/nav.php'); ?>
```

I'm not sure why I need to specify the path for the include when an anchor link has no trouble finding the same file using a relative path:

```
<a href="/includes/nav.php">Find nav include</a>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>  relative to your doc root (where presumably your script is running from, or your include path is set).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?> without success, even on a file that resides in the root folder. I think it was a misunderstanding of mine that the document root for Apache would also dictate paths for PHP.  I tried this instead, and it works: <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/include-nav.php'); and if I echo the variable it gives me "/Applications/MAMP/projects/journalproject". I was hoping for a neater approach. I guess I will keep using <?php include('../includes/nav.php'); ?>

Comment: glad you found some success.  You can also specify an INCLUDE PATH in PHP and those paths will be searched for your includes/requires.  This way you can specify files relative to the include path without being conscious of where your specific .php file that calls the include/require is located:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php      i.e. `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the below doesn't work because it is being treated as an absolute path, as it starts with a "/" which tells PHP to look from the literal "/" directory in Unix Operating Systems:
    `<?php include('/includes/nav.php'); ?>`

Try:
    `<?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

you can specify files relative to the include path without being conscious of where your specific .php file that calls the include/require is located:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])`